# Keras example word-level model with integer sequences gives `expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, word-embedding

I'm trying to implement the Keras word-level example on [their blog](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) listed under the *Bonus Section* -> **What if I want to use a word-level model with integer sequences?**

I've marked up the layers with names to help me reconnect the layers from a loaded model to a inference model later. I think I've followed their example model:

```
# Define an input sequence and process it - where the shape is (timesteps, n_features)
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, src_vocab), name='enc_inputs')
# Add an embedding layer to process the integer encoded words to give some 'sense' before the LSTM layer
encoder_embedding = Embedding(src_vocab, latent_dim, name='enc_embedding')(encoder_inputs)
# The return_state constructor argument configures a RNN layer to return a list where the first entry is the outputs
# and the next entries are the internal RNN states. This is used to recover the states of the encoder.
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True, name='encoder_lstm')(encoder_embedding)
# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state of the RNN.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, target_vocab), name='dec_inputs')
decoder_embedding = Embedding(target_vocab, latent_dim, name='dec_embedding')(decoder_inputs)
# The return_sequences constructor argument, configuring a RNN to return its full sequence of outputs (instead of
# just the last output, which the defaults behavior).
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, name='dec_lstm')(decoder_embedding, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_outputs = Dense(target_vocab, activation='softmax', name='dec_outputs')(decoder_lstm)
# Put the model together
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

but I get

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer encoder_lstm: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

on the line

```
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = LSTM(...
```

What am I missing? Or is the example on the blog assuming a step that I've skipped?

**Update:**

And I'm training with:

```
X = [source_data, target_data]
y = offset_data(target_data)
model.fit(X, y, ...)
```

**Update 2**:

So, I'm still not quite there. I have my `decoder_lstm` and `decoder_outputs` defined like above and have fixed the inputs. When I load my model from an `h5` file and build my inference model, I try and connect to the training `model` with

```
decoder_inputs = model.input[1]  # dec_inputs (Input(shape=(None,)))
# decoder_embedding = model.layers[3]  # dec_embedding (Embedding(target_vocab, latent_dim)) 
target_vocab = model.output_shape[2]
decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='input_3')  # named to avoid conflict
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='input_4')
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
# Use decoder_lstm from the training model
# decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True)
decoder_lstm = model.layers[5] # dec_lstm
decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
```

but I get an error

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer dec_lstm: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Trying to pass `decoder_embedding` rather than `decoder_inputs` fails too.

I'm trying to adapt the example of [lstm_seq2seq_restore.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq_restore.py) but it doesn't include the complexity of the embedding layer.

**Update 3**:

When I use `decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(decoder_embedding, ...)` to build the inference model I've confirmed that `decoder_embedding` is an object of type `Embedding` but I get:

```
ValueError: Layer dec_lstm was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.embeddings.Embedding'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.embeddings.Embedding object at 0x1a1f22eac8>, <tf.Tensor 'input_3:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'input_4:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

The full code for this model is on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/niccottrell/nmt-keras/src/master/models/attention2.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the input shape of `Input` layer. An embedding layer accepts a sequence of integers as input which corresponds to words indices in a sentence. Since here the number of words in sentences is not fixed, therefore you must set the input shape of `Input` layer as `(None,)`.

I think you are mistaking it with the case that we don't have an Embedding layer in our model and therefore the input shape of the model is `(timesteps, n_features)` to make it compatible with LSTM layer.

**Update:**

You need to pass the `decoder_inputs` to the Embedding layer first and then pass the resulting output tensor to the `decoder_lstm` layer like this:

```
decoder_inputs = model.input[1] # (Input(shape=(None,)))
# pass the inputs to the embedding layer
decoder_embedding = model.get_layer(name='dec_embedding')(decoder_inputs) 

# ...

decoder_lstm = model.get_layer(name='dec_lstm') # dec_lstm
decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(decoder_embedding, ...)
```

**Update 2:**

In training time, when creating the `decoder_lstm` layer you need to set `return_state=True`:

```
decoder_lstm, _, _ = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='dec_lstm')(decoder_embedding, initial_state=encoder_states)
```

Comment: Thanks - fixed my inputs! And my `encoder_inputs` and `decoder_inputs` are now integers, but since `decoder_embedding` is a dense layer - it's still expecting 3-dims. So do I just offset the integers, and then one-hot them? Is there a way to avoid the one-hot encoding for the `decoder_outputs` ?

Comment: @NicCottrell `decoder_embedding` is not a dense layer; rather it is an embedding layer. It's like a look-up table: you give it the index of the word and it gives you its corresponding word vector. So it expects an array of integers as input which, as I said, corresponds to the word indices in a sentence.

Comment: @NicCottrell Did my comment make sense? Is there still any confusion?

Comment: I'm still struggling. I've updated the question with some more code snippets. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @NicCottrell The input of `dec_lstm` layer is `dec_embedding` layer. Are you sure you get errors in that case as well? What does it says? Make sure you are retrieving the layers correctly. Since you have assigned names on layers, try retrieving them using their names by `model.get_layer(name=layer_name)` instead of using index. Let me know of the result.

Comment: Thanks @today. With `dec_embedding` I'm getting the `isn't a symbolic tensor` error. I've updated the question and linked to the full model source code if you care to take a look.

Comment: @NicCottrell You have forgotten to pass the input of the embedding layer. As the error suggests, the inputs to another layer must be tensors whereas you are passing the embedding layer itself to `dec_lstm` layer and not its output tensor. So you must first pass the `decoder_inputs` to `decoder_embedding` and then pass the output tensor to `decoder_lstm`. Sorry that I didn't notice this at the first time.

Comment: Thanks again. So I did as you instructed in updates and it's better, but called decoder_lstm gives `TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.`

Comment: @NicCottrell Oops! In which line that error occurs?

Comment: On line 84:  `decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(decoder_embedding, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)` So still something wrong with `dec_embedding` I guess. I've pushed my latest code to Bitbucket

Comment: @NicCottrell Aha! I found it: you have forgotten to set `return_state=True` when creating `decoder_lstm` layer in `dense_model` function. Just ignore the returned states in training time (i.e. use `_` as return variable); you need them in inference time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178270/discussion-between-nic-cottrell-and-today).